# Keytool creates key with wrong password

Tags: java, keytool, jks

The problem I'm having with Jetty not liking my Java Keystore boils down to this, I think:

Generate a new keystore (I've included the password for clarity):

```
keytool -keystore mark.jks -alias markkey -genkey -keyalg RSA
Enter keystore password: password
Re-enter new password: password
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  Mark
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  MarkProject
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  MarkCo
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  MarkTown
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  Markia
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  UK
Is CN=Mark, OU=MarkProject, O=MarkCo, L=MarkTown, ST=Markia, C=UK correct?
  [no]:  yes
Enter key password for <markkey> password
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):  
Re-enter new password: password
```

So I should have a keystore with password `password`, containing a key with password `password` -- correct?  (BTW: if I press `RETURN` for `same as keystore password` the results are the same.)

Try to change the passwords:

```
keytool -keypasswd -new changeit -keystore mark.jks -storepass changeit -alias markkey -keypass password
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

How can this be?  What have I done wrong or misunderstood, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your session transcript says:

```
keytool -keystore mark.jks -alias markkey -genkey -keyalg RSA
Enter keystore password: password
Re-enter new password: password
```

But then you do

```
keytool .... -keystore mark.jks -storepass changeit ....
                                           ^^^^^^^^
```

It will be this incorrect *keystore* password that it's complaining about.